# Adding NSUserDefaults to an iPhone checklist

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, data-persistence

I'm pretty damn new to iPhone development and I'm trying to get a checklist going with persistent data. I'm using a table with a checklist using [code from this tutorial].[1](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)

I've been trying on my own for a week or two trying to make this work with NSUserDefaults, but as I said I'm pretty new, and although I prefer to figure these things out with the help of google, I either don't quite know how to search for what I want or I'm not smart enough yet to figure it out from what I've found. Basically, the checklist part works, cells all get the proper accessory when checked and unchecked, but I want them to stay persistent through close.

I know this is a pretty noob question, so it would help VERY MUCH if someone could post code for what I need, but any help I can get would be GREATLY appreciated.

Edit: Added Code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self tableView: self.tableView  accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray bjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];

    [item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];

    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage   imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;

    return cell;
}

- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

    [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;

    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//Set a value
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"check1"];
//Save immediately
[defaults synchronize];

//Retrieve the value for check1
BOOL retrieved = [defaults boolForKey:@"check1"];
```

**Update**

If your dataArray only contains dictionaries with bools and strings in it then you can save the entire dataArray to `NSUserDefaults`. The following code is untested but should be close to what you will need to persist your values.

```
-(id)yourInitMethod
{
    dataArray = [(NSArray*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dataArrayKey"] mutableCopy];
    //Replace dictionaries with a mutable copy
    for(int i = 0; i < [dataArray count]; i++)
    {
        //Your dictionary that you want to be mutable
        NSMutableDictionary *aCopy = [(NSDictionary*)[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
        [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:aCopy];
        [aCopy release];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

    [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //Save the updated data array
    [defaults setObject:dataArray forKey:@"dataArrayKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Should that go in the app delegate in didFinishLaunching/appWillTerm? or should it be in the .m? If so, where? I've tried all the NSUserDefault examples I could find, and although I haven't tried exactly that code I think I'm putting it in the wrong place.

Comment: So where ever you have your code that has the checks you can save the value to NSUserDefaults. When that view loads just read all of the different defaults and when ever you save changes just write them all back and synchronize.

Comment: It would go in your .m file whenever you wanted to write out the values so either in an IBAction of some kind or after you process their information.

Comment: Did I beat you to it again Ian :)

Comment: Clearly :). All over that like a fat kid on a cupcake.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience guys, I'm gonna give that a try and let you know what happens. You guys are awesome!

Comment: Sorry that took a while, lunch...
Sorry if this is a stupid question, but where does retrieved come from...in BOOL retrieved = [defaults bookForkey:@"check1"]? I've got the save set up and I don't see any issues or warnings or anything. Again thanks a ton guys.

Comment: Whenever you want to load the values, for example if you were saving user preferences, they would want to know where they currently are and that is where you would read them out.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I think I have the saving working but on loading, the line BOOL retrieved =etcetc, I'm not sure where "retrieved is coming from" obviously xcode says it's an unused variable or a pointer issue or something, what is that supposed to be (in reference to the code I'm using from that tutorial)?

Comment: Anything you want to make it. `myChecklistItem.checked = [defaults boolForKey:@"check1"];` for example. What ever key you save your boolean to is the same key you use to retrieve it and store it where ever you like. And obviously you can store and retrieve other data types in the `NSUserDefaults` just check the documentation.

Comment: I get that (I hope) it's just when I go to run it, I always get an unused variable warning with the BOOL retrieved line, I've tried doing a few different things but always get that error. I ran it anyway to try it and it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I should just say screw it

Comment: The unused warning is from you not using it. You only need that code wherever you need to retrieve the value again.

Comment: OHHHHHHH!!!! Damn I feel dumb. LOL wow, alright lemme try to fix that . Thanks Joe!

Comment: crap...now the checks don't show. I know this is asking a lot but if I posted the .m could you show me where to put it in? I think at this point I would understand if I could just see it, because obviously everything I'm trying is only making it worse.

Comment: Mark this question answer and start up a new question if this question helped. Or you can edit your question if it closely related to the original question.

Comment: posted, can't mark as answer, got no rep! I'm new like I said. Thanks so much boss

Comment: So I tried the code you posted, I tried putting the loading part in the viewDidLoad, that caused the view to load with a blank table. I do have a plist with just strings and bool's. I replaced "dataArray" with my array thats being loaded from a plist.

Comment: Btw I forgot to mention I tried the load in a few places, sometimes instead of a blank table I would get a table with just the first entry in the array.

Comment: That example is if you already have data inside of the user defaults. Check out the registerDefaults method of `NSUserDefaults`. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html. I will be off to do some drinking soon so I might not be back until Monday.

Comment: Alright thanks Joe, have a good one. I'll let ya know if I figure it out.